# How to close the connection in Spring Boot after jdbcTemplate executes the query?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

In Spring Boot, does jdbcTemplate not close the connection automatically once after the it executes the query?
In this case, I am executing a query using jdbcTemplate(where it connects to teradata) but the session is not closing after the query is executed. How can I close the session?

This is my dao file -

```
@Component
public class DDLReviewDao { 

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("devbJdbc")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DDLReviewDao.class);

    public List<DDLObject> getDDLReviewData(DDLQuery ddlQuery) {

        String selectSql = MacroGenerator.generateMacro(ddlQuery);                  
        List<DDLObject> ddlObject = jdbcTemplate.query(selectSql, new DDLMapper());                 
        logger.info(ddlObject);
        return ddlObject;
    }

}
```

Comment: Plz share pom.xml if your are using maven.

Comment: If you look inside the source, you will see every execute or query closes it resultSet and connection so you do not need to manually close them.

Answer (score 7):

`JdbcTemplate` gets its connections from `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation - which is passed to its constructor [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#JdbcTemplate-javax.sql.DataSource-).

The `DataSource`s can be **basic** (creates `Connection` object for each request) or **pooling** (has pool of connections and just 'borrows' one for given request's use).

So, it appears that the connection is not closing because you have passed some pooling datasource to `JdbcTemplate` named `devbJdbc`. If you realy want to close every connection opened to do the `JdbcTemplate` job, you can use a basic `DataSource` implementation: `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource` just like that:

```
@Configuration
class DevbConfig {

    @Bean(name = "devbDataSource")
    DataSource devbDataSource() {
        try {
            return new SimpleDriverDataSource(DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:..."), "jdbc:...", "username", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Bean(name = "devbJdbc")
    JdbcTemplate devbJdbc(@Qualifier("devbDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> In Spring Boot, does jdbcTemplate not close the connection
>   automatically once after the it executes the query?

Should it close the connection or return it to the connection pool (in case the DataSource is pooled)?

If you read the source code at http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#JdbcTemplate.execute%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCallback%29it boils down to:

```
public static void doReleaseConnection(Connection con, DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
    if (con == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (dataSource != null) {
        ConnectionHolder conHolder = (ConnectionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(dataSource);
        if (conHolder != null && connectionEquals(conHolder, con)) {
            // It's the transactional Connection: Don't close it.
            conHolder.released();
            return;
        }
    }
    logger.debug("Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource");
    doCloseConnection(con, dataSource);
}
```

and

```
public static void doCloseConnection(Connection con, DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
    if (!(dataSource instanceof SmartDataSource) || ((SmartDataSource) dataSource).shouldClose(con)) {
        con.close();
    }
}
```

Most-likely, if the DataSource instance is pooled, connections are release back for reuse and not closed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the spring boot docs you can allocate a maximum number of connections to a spring pool like so:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
```

This will obviously only work with the embedded webserver. If you are deploying it to something like a Jboss you'll have to configure that property in the Server config file.